# export PATH not saving

Tags: bash

I'm trying to install the Google SDK

I type:

`export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Users/morganallen/Dropbox/google_appengine`

then:

`echo $PATH`

And I see:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/morganallen/Dropbox/google_appengine`

But when I quit terminal and re-open it and type `echo $PATH` I only see:

`/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

Why isn't it saving?

I've seen other answers mentioning a `.bashrc` file, but I can't find mine? Not sure what to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you type that into the command line, it only applies for the current session (until you close the bash window). Instead, save that line of code into your `.bash_profile` and it should work for every single session.

Comment: Got it! I don't think I have a `.bash_profile`, how do I create one?

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: On Mac OS X, I know that you can type `vim ~/.bash_profile` to open it. Once in vim, press `a` to edit the file, paste your code, press esc to stop editing and type `ZZ` after esc to exit vim and save settings.

Comment: Also, as @Hiren mentioned,typing ls -a shows even hidden files.

Answer (score 0):

A file whose name begins with a period (.) is a hidden file. Depending on the file manager/browser which you may be using, hidden files may not be shown by default. You will need to enable viewing hidden files in the preferences/options as the case may be.

If you are using a command line to list the contents, you can use `ls -a` instead of plain `ls`.

And of course, if you need to modify the hidden file using a text editor at the command line itself, (say, using vim/nano etc.) then you can always supply the full name of the file as an argument (including the period).

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: Because as mentioned in the question, he is not able to find the .bashrc file . I know he should have been looking for .bash_profile instead, but the solution to locating such files remains the same.